# How to check if CSS3 enabled hardware acceleration?

Tags: css

I have the following css.

> ```
> -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
> -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
> -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
> -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
> transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
>
> -webkit-transition: height 450ms cubic-bezier(0.840, 0.005, 0.755, 0.995);
> -moz-transition: height 450ms cubic-bezier(0.840, 0.005, 0.755, 0.995); 
> -ms-transition: height 450ms cubic-bezier(0.840, 0.005, 0.755, 0.995); 
> -o-transition: height 450ms cubic-bezier(0.840, 0.005, 0.755, 0.995); 
> transition: height 450ms cubic-bezier(0.840, 0.005, 0.755, 0.995);
> ```

I learned that **translate3d** enables hardware acceleration, but how do I check it? My eyes can't tell the difference.

Comment: Do some heavy animations and open it on mobile with and without hardware acceleration. You might notice a difference then. Not much difference if you're on a desktop with medium-decent hardware.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté // that should work....